# How does solar PV modules array Power, Voltage in Series/Parallel affect maximum power efficiency

Tags: power, solar-cell, homework, solar-energy

I have been struggling with my homework on my course (Solar PV Panels) today.

Edit : PV Module parameters are below.

[image]

These are for STC. In our case, it's 650 W/m^2 and 55°C. I have calculated IL and Is values for these parameters.
[image]

MATLAB plots for I-V are below.
[image]

We have 12 solar panels, also we have a 3.1 ohm load. I am trying to calculate in theory, but I am stuck. What is the best  connecting option (3 parallel 4 series, 2 parallel 6 series, etc.) for getting the maximum power?

Thank you for all help.

Comment: Always best to connect in series as long as it's within the voltage limits as Ploss=R*I^2

Comment: Please specify panel voltage, desired Vout if specified, ANY other information known. As worded Damien is correct - there is probably more to the question that we need to know.

Comment: This question can be reopened if you provide enough useful information.

Comment: @Damien  is incorrectly assuming series is best when MPP is actually at matched impedance or Zmpp=Vol/Isc = load to match

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 unless you are buying different series/type of panels, they are always pretty well matched because panels are sorted at manufacturing. I happen to make the machines that do this sorting.

Comment: @Damien yes  but that isn’t what I said matched to load Z

Comment: This is an excellent EE question contrary to moderator action

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 - Hi, (a) If you want to criticise moderator actions, then you really should take it up on Meta. Writing it in comments may not be seen by a mod (and is off-topic). (b) The question was closed by community voting, not by a mod, so it's unclear what mod action you meant :-( If you are going to criticise, then at least be specific, please (and put it on Meta). Nothing will change with *vague accusations*. (c) You said it's an excellent question, so I'm puzzled why you didn't vote to reopen it. Was there a technical problem? (d) After info was added by the OP, I have reopened it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - Hi, Info was added by the OP so I have reopened the question.